# Saving graphics in Adobe Illustrator .ai format

Tags: graphics, export

How do I save a `ListLinePlot` graphic as an *Adobe Illustrator* file (with extension `.ai`)?

Comment: .AI is not a [supported format](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListingOfAllFormats.html). `Export` is the relevant command.

Comment: With `$ExportFormats`you get all supported Formats. Check out this [link](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html) (@Jens)

Comment: Can Illustrator import PDF?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, but Adobe Illustrator's support of PDF is [limited](http://printplanet.com/forums/adobe/14831-convert-pdf-illustrator#post90866).

Answer (score 6):

Mathematica cannot export to Illustrator format.   However, it can export both to PDF and EPS, which are natively supported by Illustrator.  (In fact, <del>I believe the AI format is based on PostScript too, just like EPS</del> the AI format used to the based on EPS but is now based on PDF.)

Try using PDF or EPS instead.

The information on [Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/245/jens)'s [site](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#CopyToIllustrator) will be useful too.

Comment: If you look at the header of an AI file, it's actually just a `PDF` file with some additions. That's why it can for example be viewed in `Preview` on OS X without having to install Illustrator. AI format used to be based on EPS, but that's no longer the case.

Comment: @Jens Thank you for the explanation, corrected.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];

Export["C:\\YourPath\\plot.pdf", a]
```